# How can I add new results to an existing variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I get first ten objects from server and store it in $scope.data. It looks like this:

```
$scope.check = function(search, count) {                    
    request.getData(search, count).success(function(response) {
        $scope.data = response;
    });
};
```

When user scrolls down I'd like to add next ten objects to $scope.data and repeat these 20 objects in html with ng-repeat. Later 30, 40, etc..

```
  <ul scroll>
    <li ng-repeat="element in data">
      {{element.id}}
      {{element.name}}
      {{element.surname}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

This is my php:

```
   while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    
    $array[] = array("id"=>(int) $data['ID'], "name"=>$data['FirstName'], "surname"=>$data['LastName'], "mobile"=>$data['MobilePhone']);
   }
   echo json_encode($array);
```

And it returns something like this:

```
[{"id":885,"name":"Jeremy","surname":"Goodrow","mobile":"+48-792-518-774"},{"id":886,"name":"Noella","surname":"Modestino","mobile":"+48-792-518-774"},{"id":887,"name":"Lief","surname":"Regoli","mobile":"+48-792-518-774"}]
```

So, my question is: how can I add new ten results to existing variable ($scope.data)? When I add it at first time I do this and it works great:

```
$scope.data = response;
```

But how must I add new ten results to this variable? Response from the server is the same each time. I can't do something like this, because it does'nt work:

```
$scope.data += response;
```

Also I can't push response to $scope.data, because ng-repeat shows it like this:
[image]

Resulst are not separated. Please, help me. Maybe, I must push elements to $scope.data, but what must I change in my ng-repeat? I don't know.

Comment: like `$scope.data = $scope.data.concat(response);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use native array function concat:

```
var recievedData = []; //at the begining

$http.get('/url').success(function (responseData) {
  $scope.data = recievedData.concat(responseData);
});
```

But try to avoid this situation when the data from the server is already in the local data variable. Then you need to use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to keep it clean and unique.

Comment: [array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) : _The concat() method returns a **new** array_, so if you simple do concat _$scope.data_ not changed

Comment: yep, sorry,  `$scope.data = $scope.data.concat(responseData);`